# run standalone appscript deployed as webapp through a button in spreadsheet (which is a bounded function)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to run an app script that is deployed as a web app with, run as ME, and allows any user with a Google account to access it. The trigger to run the web app should be a button in the google spreadsheet. The function in web app has no arguments and no return values it does a lot of condition checks opens multiple files and performs a certain task. I am unable to trigger this standalone function using a bounded script.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to start a web app from a spreadsheet is to use a link instead of a button. It would be something like this:

`=hyperlink("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwn2BhBcX0ipQBrpdKymDA8ygqq3lr3aBWM13LuLqFOAgbbhNpu/exec", "Start my fancy web app")`

To use a button to launch the web app, try the pattern shown at [How to open URL via Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/b8d3bb1c309879e1547bffbd0fbf2071).